# HP BL460c Gen8 Product name change

Tags: hp-proliant, ipmi, ipmitool

After replacing the system board in a HP BL460c Gen8 Server blade,the Product name had changed from "Proliant BL460c Gen8" to "StoreEasy3830 Gtwy Blade". This is some thing that you can not change in BIOS settings. I believe both products use the same system board spare P/N 738239-001. Could someone please let me know how to change this. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to change it?

Comment: Hi MadHatter  The issue is the Onboard Administrator is reporting the Product name as "StoreEasy3830 Gtwy Blade" not as "Proliant BL460c Gen8"  which should be a server blade not a storage blade.  It's confusing when you try to identify the server.Thanks. Regards.

Comment: If you think this board is actually faulty, or genuinely the wrong part, return it to the vendor for replacement.  If this is something that such a board may legitimately say, but you're not used to seeing it, then it's time to update your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is only a guess, IPMI allows you to configure a number of settings such as "system name", "OS name", and such.  It's not clear how you're reading "Product Name", but its possible one of these settings could map to the "Product Name".

A quick skim of ipmitool's manpage doesn't indicate if they support this configuration (it's possible it does and I just can't find it).  In FreeIPMI, its configured via the bmc-device tool (i.e. bmc-device --set-system-name FOO).

Disclaimer: Maintainer of FreeIPMI, so I know these tools better than ipmitool.

Comment: Hi Albert Chu Thanks for your reply. I used ipmitool raw commands successfully to change the product ID, but I couldn't find the raw command to change the Product Name field. I haven't used FreeIPMI. I will download it and give it a go. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Albert Chu I have installed freeIPMI (v 1.1.5) on a Ubuntu 15.04 PC and tested it on a HP Prolinat 360 G5 as the real blade server is in production. I couldn't install the latest freeIPMI v 1.5.7. the fru command was successful.

Comment: see below: root@mysys:/usr/sbin# ipmi-fru -h 192.168.0.99 -u Administrator -p password -D LAN_2_0
FRU Inventory Device: Default FRU Device (ID 00h)

  FRU Chassis Type: Rack Mount Chassis
  FRU Chassis Part Number: ABCDEF          
  FRU Chassis Serial Number: 12345           

  FRU Board Manufacturing Date/Time: 01/01/96 - 00:00:00
  FRU Board Manufacturer: HP
  FRU Board Product Name: ProLiant DL360 G5
  FRU Board Serial Number: 12345           
  FRU Board Part Number: ABCDEF          

  FRU Error: product info area checksum invalid

Comment: What I want to achive is to change the "FRU Board Product Name: ProLiant DL360 G5" into some thing else. I used the bmc-device tool but it didn't like the command. 
/usr/sbin# bmc-device -h 192.168.0.99 -u Administrator -p password --set-system-name=MYSYSTEM -D LAN_2_0
ipmi_cmd_set_system_info_parameters_system_name_first_set: bad completion code

Appreciate if you could please help. Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: If you're trying to change FRU, changing system name probably will do what you want.  Unfortunately it'll probably be OEM specific magic in which you'll have to ask vendor about.

Comment: Hi Albert Chu Thanks for your reply. So the reason why the command --set-system-name=MYSYSTEM would not work is because it could be a vendor specific parameter?

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix. When blade is posting, click into the “F9” bios screen, a blue box will open, click down about 11 rows to “SERVER ASSET TEXT” & click. A gray box will open & click on “SERVER INFO TEXT”, there you will see the “wrong name” you want to change in a blue box, click on that and you can EDIT that name out & type in the name of what you like, ie: “BL460C-G8”. Hit ENTER key to exit then hit the “ESCAPE” key 3 times to exit, hit F10 to save changes. 
You will not see changes in the O/A until you click out of that blade & onto another column (I click on “POWER & THERMAL” tab and then click back to “Device Bay” & click back on that particular blade & you should see a name change. This will also change if you do a reboot on that blade. If you still don’t see a name change, go back to the same procedures in the F9 bios tab again & see if it did indeed change, if not, edit again but that is your fix.